# How do I properly test share functionality using Facebook's web hosting?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

I am developing an HTML5 game for the Facebook platform. I am using Facebook's Web Hosting product to host the game and I have created a test version of the app to see if it works properly on Facebook.

Despite having added the open graph meta tags to the games HTML code, when I test the game and try to share it using the share dialog, all the information in the meta tags is ignored. The title, the description, the image, none of them are used.

I have used Facebook's share debugger, but it claims none of the meta tags are set. The documentation is not really helpful in this specific case.

These are my open graph tags:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://apps.facebook.com/kanji-climber/" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Kanji Climber" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Test your kanji knowledge! How high can you climb?" />
<meta property="og:type" content="game">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="172026516880138" />
```

This is the function call I use for sharing:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: 'https://apps.facebook.com/kanjiclimber',

}, function(response){});
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `https://apps.facebook.com/kanjiclimber` redirects to the 404 page for me, which likely means you have not made it public yet. Set it public, and then see what the FB debug tool has to say. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: I think the only way to make a game using Facebook Web Hosting public is by submitting it to the approval process. Which would create a very backwards work flow: Have a game approved in order to be able to fully test it. How can I test open graph features in a game using Facebook Web Hosting without having to send it through the approval process first?

Comment: No, you can just set the app to “public” without submitting for review. (It might alert you that you need to set a valid privacy policy URL first, but that is the only requirement. And that PP does not even have to contain sensible content - as long as the URL is reachable by Facebook, the automatic checks in the background are satisfied. Just don’t forget to supply an actual privacy policy before you actually submit for review later on, should you just use a dummy address now ...)